# How to make application force Internet Explorer into the desktop browser profile

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am working on an application (that can only be used in Internet Explorer) and I need the application to force IE into the desktop browsing profile.

The browser starts in enterprise mode when the application starts and that browsing profile only goes up to **Internet Explorer 8 (IE8)**.

I need the application to force IE into the desktop browsing profile so it can use **IE11**.

I am currently using the code:
      `<meta http-eqiv="X-UA-Compatible" Content="IE="110" />` so 
the application will force Internet Explorer into IE11. This does not work when the browser emulates the application in the enterprise browsing profile when it is opened.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this an internal "corporate" type application? If not, what are you going to do with systems like mine, a non-windows system which doesn't even have internet explorer? Internet explorer has also been replaced by Edge; what are you going to do with systems that only have Edge, no IE?  If this is a browser-based application you should write to _web standards_, not to any particular browser.

Comment: This is a corporate application and we only use internet explorer. If the applications are opened in another browser, they are redirected to internet explorer.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted... it's a perfectly sensible question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if we want to open IE browser from another browser, we should install the "protocol handlers" for another browser (such as: Chrome, which would let you send a link like ie://example.com/path/to/app). The protocol handler would launch IE and take you to the relevant site. But your users would have to install the handler (and, of course, you'd have to write it). So, I think it might not a good choice. You could think about it.

I suggest you could try to create a Windows Forms application, and use the WebBrowser control to display the website. You can use the WebBrowser control to duplicate Internet Explorer Web browsing functionality in your application or you can disable default Internet Explorer functionality and use the control as a simple HTML document viewer. More detail information about using WebBrowser control, please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview).